# Перевести текст для волшебной ссылки на MCVE

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

`[mcve]` в комментариях к вопросам заменяется на
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507149/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-python#comment611423_507149)).

А хотелось бы чтобы заменялось на
[Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (или любой другой перевод на русский).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Поправил.