# В шпаргалке по комментариям пропущен [mcve]

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В русской шпаргалке по [форматированию комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) пропущена строка про `[mcve]`, которая есть в [английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting):

> [mcve] – link to /help/mcve, with the link text "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Описание появилось, но на английском.

Comment: Должно обновиться (быть на русском) в ближайшее время.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Через 24 часа текст по прежнему английский. Может быть, разработчики забыли подключить переводы к этой строке и показывают ее "как есть"? И, кстати, на русской Мете тоже [надо добавить](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: Скорее всего, просто не выкатывали новую сборку. [Строку я перевел, честно](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/85429184?q=with%20the%20link%20text)!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Текст поменялся на русский. Ура, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky На Мете [mcve] не только отсутствует в шпаргалке по комментариям, но и вообще не работает в комментариях. Для порядка хотелось бы, чтобы на Мете  работало всё, что работает на сайте. Но если ряди этого нужно долго бодать разработчиков, то я не уверен, нужно ли тратить время.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, на Мете и нет mcve, так как нет справки вообще. (Попробуйте http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Получается, на справке стоит редирект и основная часть функционала - общая с основным сайтом. Но есть "расщелины", в которых видно, что на Мете используется самостоятельная и недообновлённая версия движка. Ситуация житейская и достаточно адекватная, но надо иметь её в виду. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Не совсем понял про « расщелины». На Мете нет ни справки, ни тура.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта волшебная ссылка заработала на русском SO [позже остальных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2745/). Поэтому её [позже перевели](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2767/) и поэтому её нет в подсказке по форматированию комментариев.

На Мете сделан [список волшебных ссылок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2709/), но его надо уметь отыскать, а шпаргалка открывается по ссылке из окна комментария.

Чтобы исправить дефект, надо добавить [в русскую шпаргалку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) строку. Например, такую:

> `[mcve]` – ссылка на страницу [«Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).